# Materail UI v5 TextField component caues Jest test to fail

Tags: jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library, emotion

I recently upgraded from Material UI v4 to v5.  It seems there is some kind of incompatibility with my Jest tests since now I get the following error when attempting to render a TextField.  The test runs fine if I use the component from MUI v4.  The component renders fine when viewing the page in the browser.

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘setAttribute’)]
        at reportException (/home/node_modules/jest-config/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:66:24)
        at innerInvokeEventListeners (/home/node_modules/jest-config/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:341:9)
        at invokeEventListeners (/home/node_modules/jest-config/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
        at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (/home/node_modules/jest-config/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
        at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/home/node_modules/jest-config/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (/home/node_modules/jest-config/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (/home/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4210:16)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (/home/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4274:31)
        at reportUncaughtErrorInDEV (/home/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22737:5)
        at captureCommitPhaseError (/home/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27078:5) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘setAttribute’)
        at /home/node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-react.cjs.dev.js:206:12

 console.error
    The above error occurred in the <EmotionGlobal> component:

    at /home/node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-e89f38a3.cjs.dev.js:64:23
    at GlobalStyles (/home/node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/node/GlobalStyles/GlobalStyles.js:28:5)
    at GlobalStyles
    at InputBase (/home/node_modules/@mui/material/node/InputBase/InputBase.js:251:44)
    at OutlinedInput (/home/node_modules/@mui/material/node/OutlinedInput/OutlinedInput.js:135:44)
    at div
    at /home/node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-e89f38a3.cjs.dev.js:64:23
    at FormControl (/home/node_modules/@mui/material/node/FormControl/FormControl.js:111:44)
    at /home/node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-e89f38a3.cjs.dev.js:64:23
    at TextField (/home/node_modules/@mui/material/node/TextField/TextField.js:107:44)
    at div
    at /home/node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-e89f38a3.cjs.dev.js:64:23
    at Box (/home/node_modules/@mui/system/createBox.js:41:41)
    at div
    at /home/node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-e89f38a3.cjs.dev.js:64:23
    at Box (/home/node_modules/@mui/system/createBox.js:41:41)
    at form
    at CreateNewCVForm (/home/src/project/sciencv/static/sciencv/js/index/CreateNewCVForm.js:16:41)
    at div
    at /home/node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-e89f38a3.cjs.dev.js:64:23
    at Box (/home/node_modules/@mui/system/createBox.js:41:41)
    at div
    at /home/node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-e89f38a3.cjs.dev.js:64:23
    at CVListPage (/home/src/project/sciencv/static/sciencv/js/CVListPage.js:77:
```

Here is my package.json.  I believe I upgraded to latest version of the various libraries that are being used to run the tests.  I tried passing in the required / non-required attributes that are used by the component.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-self": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.3",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.83",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.1",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.8.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "clone": "^2.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "jest-teamcity-reporter": "^0.9.0",
    "loglevel": "^1.7.1",
    "marked": "^1.2.9",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.1.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.10.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.43.4",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.4.3",
    "url-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.4.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
  }
```

Comment: Looks like something related to `GlobalStyles`. Are you importing it from `@mui/material`? Also `@mui/styles` is deprecated in v5 and you have `@material-ui/core` (related to v4). You can start checking out this imports.

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto thanks for your reply. I believe `GlobalStyles` is imported automatically by `emotion`.  My code simply imports a `TextField` from `@mui/material` and attempts to render it.  I also tried removing the other imports you mentioned and uninstalling them but get the same error.

Comment: Ok I think I have a better idea about what is causing this issue now, which is related to some custom code I have. I have this spy that overrides the implementation for retrieving the value of a CSRF token, and seems like that is conflicting another part of the code from one of the libraries.

jest.spyOn(document, 'querySelector')...

I'll work on refactoring the code and post my solution.